# Delete node with biggest values from linked list

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I want to delete the Node with the biggest generic T object from my linear linked list (list only has head) and return the object of this Node. Method signature must look like this and the code I got so far:

The List looks like this:

```
public List<T extends Comparable<T>>{

        private Node<T> head;

        public List(){
            this.head = null;
        }

        //inner class Node
        public class Node<T>{
            T obj;
            Node<T> next;
        }

        public Node(T obj){
            this.obj = obj;
        }
        //the method my question is about
        public T remove(){

            if(head == null) return null;

            else {

            Node<T> act = head;
            Node<T> prev = head //previous Node
            Node<T> biggest;

            while(act != null){
                if(act.obj.compareTo(prev.obj) > 0) {
                    biggest = act;
                }
                prev = p;
                p = p.next;
            }
            return biggest.obj;
        }
}
```

This code only gets the biggest object but does not delete the Node. I don't know how to adapt the while loop to delete the node. If I found the biggest Element the prev.next pointer must go to the act.next Node somehow.

Comment: Consider indenting your code properly if you would like people to read it.

Comment: Maybe you should post code that compiles...

Answer (score 0):

What your code currently does is it compares two adjacent nodes `if(act.obj.compareTo(prev.obj)`, where I assume nodes are not ordered by value (you did not mention it in your question), so this is incorrect.

What you want to do is:

1. Find the biggest value in the list
2. Remove node with that value

---

```
T biggestValue = head.obj;

// 1
while(act != null) {
    if(act.obj.compareTo(biggestValue.obj) > 0) {
        biggestValue = act.obj;
    }
}

// 2
while(act != null) { // that loop and its body could be simplified by using: while(!act.obj.equals(biggestValue)) but I leave it that way for brevity
    if(act.obj.equals(biggestValue)) {
        prev.next = act.next;
        break;
    }
    prev = act;
    act = act.next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If the singly linked list contains more than one item, and you want to cut out the node that contains the largest value, you have to use two while loops, the first loop to identify what is the largest value, the second loop to find the node that contains that largest value and cut it from the list.